# rails 3 + jquery post failing?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, post

Ok i have a rails 3 application and when i try to do a $.post request to a rails action I get prompted to relogin ...this might be related to the authenticity_token or the way rails 3 handles posts or remote => true ...but honestly i really dont know why its not working...here is my code

```
$('#pling').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var location = $(this).closest("form").attr("action");
    $.post(location, { note: $("#note").val() }, function(data) {
        var length = data.length;
        var div_string = "";
        for (i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            div_string += "<p style=\"font-size: 11px; padding: 0 5px;\">"+ data[i].comment.comment +"</p>";
        }
        $("#pling").html(div_string);
    });
    $("#pay").val("");
    $("#pling").animate( { backgroundColor: "#D3ECF4" }, 1 ).animate( { backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 3000 );
});
```

and here is my rails action

```
def update_note
  @user = Contact.find(params[:id])
  note = params[:note].to_s.strip
  note = "#{Time.now} - #{note.to_s} - #{current_user.name} (#{current_user.id})"
  @user.notes.create!(:note => note, :user_id => current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @user.notes}
  end
end
```

any idea what i am doing wrong

here is my form if i view source

```
<form method="post" action="/users/100/update_note?remote=true" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8">
<input type="hidden" value="yPtCzfaI5HOSWeW8HBGLthbpUmgsfgsdfgsdW4aunGDtacva6Kx0=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
```

Comment: how exactly its not working, any errors?

Comment: Sidenote. If you do: `@user.notes.create!`, you don't need to detail: `:user_id => current_user.id`

Comment: its logging me out in safari after i clear cache ...so basically the first time visiting the page.....its prompting me for login and password

Comment: What you describe in comment is basically the default behavior after a csrf counter measure in Rails.

Comment: Adding to what @apneadiving said, make sure you have this Rails UJS adapter installed so it will pass the authenticity token along with all jQuery ajax calls: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing the post directly via jquery, you should instead use the ujs helpers of rails:

```
form_for @user, :remote => true
```

and then plug yourself into the form lifecycle-methods described here http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/